# PowerShell Results Still In Array Format

Tags: azure, powershell

```
$paasResource =  (Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName xxxyyy)
$azdiag = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $paasResource.Id
$objectArr = @()

if ($azdiag.Logs -ne $null) {
    $Diag = $azdiag.Logs

    $prop = [ordered]@{
        'CategoryName' = $Diag.Category
        'CategoryEnabled' = $Diag.Enabled
    }

    $obj = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
    $objectArr += $obj
}

else {
    Write-Host $paasResource.Name "is not configured for Diagnostic Logging."
}

$objectArr | Select-object CategoryName, CategoryEnabled
```

Seems to work in terms of getting the correct information, but the output is still in an array. I attempted to use -ExpandProperty, but that did not work. Just looking for some guidance on why the results are still in the array format.

Output seen here for reference:

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "in the array format" - can you add the output you're seeing, and maybe a hand-crafted example of what you're expecting it to look like (or would like it to look like)?

Comment: output shown above. I guess I was expecting it to be in List format. As you can see, it appears to be showing the correct info, but the results are still contained within {} - which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing your output because `$azdiag.Logs` is a collection of objects. Then you are extracting all objects `Category` and `Enabled` property values and storing them into one object with new properties. The resulting new properties now contain the arrays of values.

To achieve the result you want, you need to only select your properties from the original collection using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7):

```
$paasResource =  (Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName xxxyyy)
$azdiag = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $paasResource.Id
if ($azdiag.Logs.Count -gt 0) {
    $azdiag.Logs | Select-Object @{n='CategoryName';e={$_.Category}},@{n='CategoryEnabled';e={$_.Enabled}}
}
else {
    Write-Host $paasResource.Name "is not configured for Diagnostic Logging."
}
```